# PHP - Load a file from s3, decompress it, and export it run into memory issue

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have a large csv file (100M+) generated and uploaded it to AWS S3. The file is compressed. Now I need to download the file to users, and it ran into out of memory problem.

Please see below my code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv");

$result = $this->loadFromS3(); //This returns the file from AWS S3

echo bzdecompress($result['Body']);
```

How can I adjust my code to avoid memory exhausted?

Comment: if its just 100MB maybe you can raise memory limit in php.ini a bit?

Comment: 100MB is just an example. It could be 1GB or more depending on the situation. I can't reply on changing php.ini for this. This solution is not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, dont store in $result, stream the file. Use the [Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html) and

```
$client->registerStreamWrapper();

// Open a stream in read-only mode
if ($stream = fopen('s3://bucket/test.bz2', 'r')) {
  stream_filter_append($stream, 'bzip2.decompress',STREAM_FILTER_READ);
  // While the stream is still open
  while (!feof($stream)) {
    // Read 1024 bytes from the stream
    echo fread($stream, 1024);
  }
  // Be sure to close the stream resource when you're done with it
  fclose($stream);
}
```

Comment: Hi Bretzl, thanks for your reply. I think the place that is causing a memory exhausted is when I decompress the file. Downloading the .csv.bz2 file from s3 is not that large (probably less than 1MB). But when I decompress it, all the sudden it consumes 100MB+ memory. Do you know how I can solve that?

Comment: bzdecompress returns the string. thats in memory.